# jQuery php - Submit Form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I am submitting a form with jQuery

Like this:

```
   $(function() {
        $('#addreply').submit(function(){

            $('#status').removeClass().addClass('alert info').html('Loading...').fadeIn();  
            $.post(
                '/index.php?i=pm&p=r', 
                $('form').serialize(),
                function (data) {
                    proccessData(data);
                }
            );
            return false;    
        });
    });

    function proccessData (data) {
        $('#status').hide().html('');

        if(data=='success'){
            $("#post").append('<li class="current-user"><img width="30" height="30" src="<?php echo $userdata['avatar'] ?>"><div class="bubble"><a class="user-name"><?php echo $userdata['username']; ?></a><p class="message">'+ $("#message").val() +'</p><p class="time"></p></div></li>');
            $('#message').val('');
        $(".widget-content").animate({ scrollTop: $('.widget-content')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000); 


        }
        else {
            $('#status').removeClass().addClass('alert error').html(data).fadeIn();
        }
    }
```

This is the PHP:

```
   if($_POST)
    {
        $replyPrivateMessage = $privateMessage->replyMessage();


            /*
            * Error codes:
            * 1 - You do not own this pm.
            * 2 - No text entered.
            * 3 - Text is too short.
            * 4 - Text is too long.
            * 5 - You have reached your PM limit.
            * 6 - Error in adding your reply. Unexpected error.
            * Success code:
            * 100 - Successfully updated.
            * 
            */ 

        switch($replyPrivateMessage)
        {

                case 1:
                    $error = 'The entered text is either too short or too long.';
                    $stop = true;
                break;
                case 2:
                    $error = 'Unexpected error.';
                    $stop = true;
                break;

                //If no error = success.    
                case 100:
                    die('success');
                break;
        }

        die($error);

    }
```

The problem is that when I submit the form (and there is no errors), it will print out "success" but it will use this:

```
$('#status').removeClass().addClass('alert error').html(data).fadeIn();
```

Because I can see that the div has the error alert error. So, it prints out "success" AND it runs the form correctly - insert into DB and all.

My questiion is, why doesn't it do this:

```
if(data=='success'){
    $("#post").append('<li class="current-user"><img width="30" height="30" src="<?php echo $userdata['avatar'] ?>"><div class="bubble"><a class="user-name"><?php echo $userdata['username']; ?></a><p class="message">'+ $("#message").val() +'</p><p class="time"></p></div></li>');
    $('#message').val('');
$(".widget-content").animate({ scrollTop: $('.widget-content')[0].scrollHeight}, 1000); 


}
```

Since the data that is received is "success"?

Comment: Could you also provide your HTML form code?

Comment: It looks like a server response type problem. To clarify the response type use the long version of the ajax call and set the dataType to "html" manually.
`$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
    url: "YOUR_URL",
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    success: proccessData,
  dataType: "html"
});`
[jQuery Post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: Your script seems to work fine, if your form contains at least one named input element. If your form does not contain any named element, I get the same result as you do.